# Create Table selecting Lines and write slope in percentage using Autolisp

Tags: lisp, autolisp

After creating lines using contour lines, within a lot, I need to create a table, after selecting all the lines, in order, where the end result shows the Lot Number and the slope in percentage. The method I'm using takes a long time to make, Using an empty table, first I extract Delta Z (B2), then, the 3D length (C2) of the same line, then apply formulas in D2 =SQR(B2) and E2 =SQR(C2), then in F2 =SQRT(D2/E2)*100 to get percentage needed. Contour lines have 2.0m height intervals.

Table in image depicts previous explanation

Comment: there's no table attached? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask